how can i fix my text overlaying on my nav bar?
if you scroll down to waffles, i have used custom checkboxes. i've managed to get the checkboxes to go under the navbar when i scroll but the text will still appear on top of the nav bar.
codepen
i am using z-index but when i use z-index: -1 on my label class, my buttons are not clickable.
<blockquote>
        <input type="checkbox" id="top1" name="top1" value="whippedcream">
        <label for="top1"> Whipped Cream - <b> $0.75 </b></label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="top2" name="top2" value="chocolatedrizzle">
        <label for="top2"> Chocolate Drizzle - <b> $0.25 </b></label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="top3" name="top3" value="pb">
        <label for="top3"> Peanut Butter - <b> $0.25 </b></label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="top4" name="top4" value="honey">
        <label for="top4"> Honey - <b> $0.25 </b></label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="top14" name="top14" value="jelly">
        <label for="top14"> Jelly - <b> $0.25 </b></label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="top5" name="top5" value="strawb">
        <label for="top5"> Strawberries - <b> $0.50 per scoop </b></label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="top6" name="top6" value="blueb">
        <label for="top6"> Blueberries - <b> $0.50 per scoop </b></label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="top7" name="top7" value="raspb">
        <label for="top7"> Raspberries- <b> $0.50 per scoop </b></label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="top8" name="top8" value="blackb">
        <label for="top8"> Blackberries - <b> $0.50 per scoop </b></label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="top9" name="top9" value="banana">
        <label for="top9"> Bananas - <b> $0.50 per scoop </b></label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="top10" name="top10" value="peach">
        <label for="top10"> Peaches - <b> $0.50 per scoop</b></label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="top11" name="top11" value="chopwal">
        <label for="top11"> Chopped Walnuts - <b> $0.50 per scoop</b></label>
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="top12" name="top12" value="choppec">
        <label for="top12"> Chopped Pecans - <b> $0.50 per scoop</b></label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="top13" name="top13" value="ps">
        <label for="top13"> Powdered Sugar - <b> $0.25 </b></label><br>
      </blockquote>

input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 25px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

label:before {
  background-color: #d74b76;
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 1px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3),
    0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  z-index: -1;
}
.checkbox label:before {
  border-radius: 3px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
  content: "\2713";
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 12px;
}



input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 25px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

label:before {
  background-color: #d74b76;
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 1px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3),
    0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  z-index: -1;
}
.checkbox label:before {
  border-radius: 3px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
  content: "\2713";
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 12px;
}
<blockquote>
        <input type="checkbox" id="top1" name="top1" value="whippedcream">
        <label for="top1"> Whipped Cream - <b> $0.75 </b></label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="top2" name="top2" value="chocolatedrizzle">
        <label for="top2"> Chocolate Drizzle - <b> $0.25 </b></label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="top3" name="top3" value="pb">
        <label for="top3"> Peanut Butter - <b> $0.25 </b></label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="top4" name="top4" value="honey">
        <label for="top4"> Honey - <b> $0.25 </b></label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="top14" name="top14" value="jelly">
        <label for="top14"> Jelly - <b> $0.25 </b></label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="top5" name="top5" value="strawb">
        <label for="top5"> Strawberries - <b> $0.50 per scoop </b></label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="top6" name="top6" value="blueb">
        <label for="top6"> Blueberries - <b> $0.50 per scoop </b></label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="top7" name="top7" value="raspb">
        <label for="top7"> Raspberries- <b> $0.50 per scoop </b></label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="top8" name="top8" value="blackb">
        <label for="top8"> Blackberries - <b> $0.50 per scoop </b></label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="top9" name="top9" value="banana">
        <label for="top9"> Bananas - <b> $0.50 per scoop </b></label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="top10" name="top10" value="peach">
        <label for="top10"> Peaches - <b> $0.50 per scoop</b></label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="top11" name="top11" value="chopwal">
        <label for="top11"> Chopped Walnuts - <b> $0.50 per scoop</b></label>
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="top12" name="top12" value="choppec">
        <label for="top12"> Chopped Pecans - <b> $0.50 per scoop</b></label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="top13" name="top13" value="ps">
        <label for="top13"> Powdered Sugar - <b> $0.25 </b></label><br>
      </blockquote>
      <p><button>Add to Cart</button></p>
    </div>
  </div>



this code snippet is just the checkboxes, u'll see the issue on the codepen

Simply assign header tag css to z-index: 2; as shown below:
header {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}

It should fix the overlap issue. Hope it helps!
